# MongoJS Node.js modules:"db is not undefined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongojs

I'm new to Node.js, MongoDB and MongoJS.

I have `app.js` which is the server I run from my command line with `node app.js`. On a local machine with OS X 10.9.1 with Node.js v0.10.28.

In `app.js` I have (as snippets)

```
var db = require('./database');

var blog = require('./classes/blog');
```

and `database.js` has

```
var db = require("mongojs");

db.connect('mydb',  ["Users", "Posts"]);
```

and `/classes/blog.js` has

```
function load(OnDone) {
    if (db.connected) {
        OnDone();
    }
}
```

When I call `blog.load()` I get

```
ReferenceError: db is not defined
    at Object.load (node/classes/blog.js:13:6)
    at node/app.js:36:7
    at Server.onRequest (node/server.js:35:12)
    at Server.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at HTTPParser.parser.onIncoming (http.js:2108:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete [as onHeadersComplete] (http.js:121:23)
    at Socket.socket.ondata (http.js:1966:22)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:527:27)
```

Everything in my app works as expected *except* when I try to call my `load()` function which uses the `db` var that I thought I declared in `app.js`.

***Why would `db` be undefined? Am I using modules wrong?***

**Note:** if you can't tell, I extracted these lines of codes from my scripts since my app so far is relatively long for a SO question and I don't want to show it all unless I need to.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Node.js modules are contained so do not have access to variables defined in their parents (as I assumed).

I moved `db` to the global namespace (I removed `var`) and it's working now.

Comment: Why not add a `require` to the `blog.js` file that properly references the DB connection?

Comment: So for every module that needs the database, require the database module?

Comment: That's what I'd suggest. That way, the sequence is always correct, and you can be assured the connection/etc. is properly established.

Comment: I'll try it. It makes sense, but I thought it'd be like PHP where if you `require()` twice it runs the required file twice.

Comment: No, required files in node run once and are cached.